# Get value from Dictionary holding generic type in C#

Tags: c#, generics

```
public class Table<T> where T:SomeClassWithIntegerID
{
    private Dictionary<int, T> map = new Dictionary<int, T>();

    public bool isInMemory(int id)
    {
        if (map.ContainsKey(id))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public T setIt(T obj)
    {
        map[obj.id] = obj;
    }

    public T getIt(int id)
    {
        return map[id];
    }
}
```

Example:

```
private static Table<User> table = new Table<User>;

class User : SomeClassWithIntegerID
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}

class SomeClassWithIntegerID
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

I can now check if the `Table` holds a user with a certain ID, because I use that as the key, but there is now no way for me to check if the `Table` holds a `User` with the `name` Bob or whatever. I want to be able to do something like `table.isInMemory(name, "bob")` but how is that possible with a generic type?

I need to create a function that allows the end user to specify the field and expected value of said field, after which Table will go over all objects of that class, stored in the Dictionary, to see if one has the field that matches that value.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Public member names in .Net should be UpperCamelCased.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: I believe you need to add something like IQueryable or something like that. I think you really need to question why you need to wrap a Dictionary like that anyway though

Comment: Or you can implement IEnumerable and you can straight forwardly run Linq queries..

Comment: You could use Reflection but that is a whole new can of worms to open. I think basically when you end up in situations like this, using a generic method might not have been the best choice. What is against defining a `Dictionary<int, User>` and use some simple Linq to get the one that you want?

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted you but +1 from me.  The question is a reasonable one to ask.

Comment: @SLaks - How do you know that his passwords are in plain text?   string doesn't necessarily mean plain text.  He could be storing off the string representation of a password hash.  But I agree with your statement... plain text passwords would be a bad thing.

Comment: @SLaks You are joking right? I wrote this example quickly enough to suit the question, and the fact that the password is a string does not mean it is stored in plain text...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public bool IsInMemory(Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return map.Values.Any(predicate);
}
```

You can then call it as:

```
table.IsInMemory(u => u.Name == "bob");
```

If you want to use a property name and value to match on you could add an overload:

```
public bool IsInMemory(string propertyName, object value)
{
    PropertyInfo property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
    if(property == null) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property name: " + propertyName);

    var predicate = new Func<T, bool>(item => object.Equals(value, property.GetValue(item, null)));
    return IsInMemory(predicate);
}
```

Comment: Yep. Sadly his T type knows nothing about Name property. If it did there would probably be no problem :)

Comment: Had same idea - I just type slowly, alas.  :)  Like the propname/value overload you show too.

Comment: Ah crap, I nearly got to this solution myself but I didn't know Values.Any existed... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would complement Lee's answer with a Where-method to enable querying with LINQ:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Where(Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return map.Values.Where(predicate);
}
```

And an example:

```
table.Where(x => x.name.Contains("natli"))
     .OrderBy(x => x.name);
```

To answer your actual question, you can (if you're using .NET 4.0) use the *dynamic* type, which resolves all methods and such at runtime, to call methods or properties that the compiler doesn't know about from its context.

```
dynamic dynObject = someObject;
dynObject.SomeMethod("Hi there", 27); // Call whatever method or property you "know" exist
```